# Replacing a String from all the files with the value from text file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file named **abcd.txt** which has content `dfunsufngsufspdfnsufbhpsdubf`

I have multiple php files, py files in a folder names /home/admin/temp
All the files have a string `replace-me`

How can I replace this? I tried using the below script

```
NODE=1
BOY="/home/opc/firewall"
GIRL="$BOY/full/temp-$NODE"

grep -rl 'replace-me' $GIRL | xargs sed -i "s/replace-me/$(cat $GIRL/abcd3.txt)/g";
```

I'll be using this in a big script. Someone please help me in such case

Comment: Why don't you use the `sed` command directly and avoid the `grep`? You would save the extra file read of the grep for no benefit.
BTW, which is the issue with your script?

Comment: @Poshi I dont know how to use, i had got that command from the web. Can you guide me what command shall I use.

Comment: The implementation would be different if `$GIRL` is a folder or a file. If it is a file, just give it to `sed` (`sed ... $GIRL`)- If it is a folder, then another question arise: do you really need recursion. If not, then feed everything to `sed` (sed ... $GIRL/*). If recursion needed, then substitute grep by find: `find $GIRL | xargs sed ...`. Be careful to adjust the commands to your needs. You should consider the possibility of spaces in filenames, which is not accounted here.

Comment: @Poshi $GIRL is a folder how can I use it? Can you show me the command?

Comment: Should `fireplace-metrics` be changed into `fidfunsufngsufspdfnsufbhpsdubftrics` or not? Always show a [mcve] with concise, testable, textal sample input and expected output and include non-trivial cases in your sample input/output as it's always easy to match text you want but harder to not match similar text you don't want. Another rainy-day case - if `dfunsufngsufspdfnsufbhpsdubf` could contain backreference chars like `&` or `\1` or delimiters like `/` you'd need a very different solution than otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to feed result from `grep` command to `sed` command:

```
  sed -i "s/replace-me/$(cat $GIRL/abcd3.txt)/g" $( grep -rl 'replace-me' $GIRL )
```